# How to convert jchar to char in JNi in Android development?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I want to convert jchar array to char array in JNI ? How should i do it :

JNI Code Snippet :

```
jcharArray arr = (jcharArray) (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, obj, mid);
int count = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, arr);
jchar* chars = (*env)->GetCharArrayElements(env, arr, 0);

char reg_chal= chars[1];
```

char reg_chal= chars[1] statement inserts garbage value into reg_chal.
How to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you'll note the [JNI documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html), a `jchar` is an unsigned 16 bit value (which makes sense, as java characters are represented by UTF-16.)  If you want an 8 bit value (the size of a C `char`) you should be using `jbyte`.