# Android send char array to JNI c++

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

Good day

I have a question how to send my char array to jni c++ code? I know how send int number only..

A have this array `char[] chars = password.toCharArray();`

and `private native void JNIEncrypt(char[] chars);`

My JNI method look like this

```
Java_com_kru13_ndkdemos_MainActivity_JNIEncrypt( JNIEnv* env, jobject  obj, ?????)
```

I would like to ask how it should look JNI method? I need use char array in c++ code

than you

Comment: While going in the opposite direction, you could probably solve your problem by reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429345/how-to-convert-jchar-to-char-in-jni-in-android-development

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pass it as a `String`, which is `jstring` in JNI:

```
// Java side
private native void JNIEncrypt(String password);

// Native JNI side
Java_com_kru13_ndkdemos_MainActivity_JNIEncrypt(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring password);
```

You can then access the string JNI side via [GetStringChars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html)() and related or [GetStringUTFChars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html)(). For example:

```
const char* utf8 = env->GetStringUTFChars(password, NULL);
// do something with utf8
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(password, utf8);
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be:

```
Java_com_kru13_ndkdemos_MainActivity_JNIEncrypt( JNIEnv* env, jobject  obj, jcharArray array)
```

Inside the function you will have to use `env->GetCharArrayElements(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

`toCharArray` gets you the sequence of Unicode/UTF-16 code-units from the string. On Android, You will probably want Unicode/UTF-8 on the C++ side, but that depends on the C++ libraries you want to use. Once, you know, use the Java `String` class to get the bytes.

Note: `GetStringUTFChars` gives you *modified UTF-8* code-units, which Unicode-compliant libraries reject for many characters.

```
private void JNIEncrypt(String string) {
    JNIEncrypt(string.getBytes("UTF-8")); 
    // Or, for the OS default, string.getBytes()
}

private native void JNIEncrypt(byte[] chars);
```